# Spark dataframe not writing Double quotes into csv file properly

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm reading a file delimited by pipe(|). There are fields having double quotes makes issue while reading and writing the data into another file.
The input file is given below.

```
123|"ABC"|hello
124|"AB|hello all
125|A"B"|hellll
```

The code is given below.

```
val myDf = session.sqlContext.read.format("csv")
      .option("charset", "UTF8")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("quote","\u0000")
      .schema(mySchema)
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
      .load("path to file")
```

When i do myDf.show() shows the output correctly in Console.
But when i write the same dataframe to CSV file, All double quotes are replaced by `\"`.

```
myDf.repartition(1).write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .save("Path to save file")
```

Output in the csv file:

```
123|"\"ABC\""|hello
124|"\"AB"|hello all
125|"A\"B\""|hellll
```

Why this happens so, Is there any way to get the csv as expected below.

```
123|"ABC"|hello
124|"AB|hello all
125|A"B"|hellll
```

Comment: Having a somewhat different issue - when using a Coalesce to create a CSV in databrics - my output gets double quotes at the start/end of every line. I already have the .option("quote", "") . When others download the same code they don't get these double quotes. Trying to find another piece of code - or a setting to change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be done by disabling both escaping and quotation

```
myDf.repartition(1).write
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("escape", "")
      .option("quote", "")
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .save("Path to save file")
```

Comment: could you please explain how and what is been disabled

Comment: @potterpod Basically both escape and quote characters are set to empty strings `.option("escape", "").option("quote", "")`